# cleaning untrusted inputs that build os commands in PHP?

Tags: php, url, code-injection, inject

how to remove untrusted inputs that build os commands from url in php?

When I running automatic testing zaproxy, I am getting an alert of P1 that is your inputs are building os commands. So I want to know how to clean those commands.

Comment: No special action required here. You obviously have to validate and sanitize _every_ single bit of data you get from clients anyway. And your implementation should _never_ allow client data to somehow get used in the execution flow, so as argument to a `require` statement or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `escapeshellarg()` and `escapeshellcmd()` to escape data for usage as shell command or argument.

```
// escapes a single argument
// sample input: "/foo/bar/"
$argument = escapeshellarg($userInput1); 
exec("ls $argument");

// escapes all special characters like [];{} for usage in command line
// sample input: "ls -l; rm -rf /"
$command = escapeshellcmd($userInput2);
exec($command);
```

You should use both commands together to prevent users from executing arbitrary commans on your server.

Documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php